# Why can't I write an HTTP response from a seperate package in Go?

Tags: http, go, httpresponse, writer

I'm using [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) to set up an API endpoint, but I'm having some trouble getting it to output a response correctly.

My main file as it stands:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "infrastructure/routing"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func testPrint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Test output.")
}

func main() {

    fmt.Printf("\n************************************\n")
    fmt.Printf("MySite Application Server\n")
    fmt.Printf("Version: %s", "Unversioned Development Build\n")
    fmt.Printf("************************************\n\n")

    router := httprouter.New()

    //////Records//////
    router.GET("/test", testPrint)
    router.GET("/records", routing.RecordList)
    router.GET("/records/id/:id", routing.RecordGetById)
    router.GET("/records/name/:name", routing.RecordGetByName)
    router.GET("/records/search/*search-string", routing.RecordSearch)
    router.HEAD("/records/:id", routing.RecordGetExists)
    router.POST("/records", routing.RecordCreate)
    router.PATCH("/records", routing.RecordUpdate)
    router.PUT("/records", routing.RecordUpsert)
    router.DELETE("/records/:id", routing.RecordDelete)
    router.DELETE("/records/:id/undelete", routing.RecordUndelete)
    router.DELETE("/records/:id/purge", routing.RecordPurge)

    fmt.Printf("Listening on port 8080...\n")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))

}
```

*Most* of the handler functions are located in `infrastructure/routing`, but this is where the problem starts. The code for routing is currently:

```
package routing

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
)

func RecordList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    //Returns a list of records.
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Returned a list of records.")
}

func RecordGetById(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Return a record with the specified ID.
    w.Write([]byte("Returned a record by its ID."))
}

func RecordGetByName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Returns a record with the specified string in the name field.
    w.Write([]byte("Returned a record by its name."))
}

func RecordSearch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Full text search for the search term provided.
    w.Write([]byte("Search results."))
}

func RecordGetExists(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Returns whether a record exists.
    w.Write([]byte("Returns whether a record exists. Should usually return 200 or 404."))
}

func RecordCreate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Creates new records from JSON data in request body.
    w.Write([]byte("Creates new records."))
}

func RecordUpdate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Updates records using JSON data in request body.
    w.Write([]byte("Updates existing records."))
}

func RecordUpsert(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Updates existing records and creates new ones using JSON data in request body.
    w.Write([]byte("Upserts records."))
}

func RecordDelete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Marks the record with the specified ID as deleted.
    w.Write([]byte("Marks records as deleted."))
}

func RecordUndelete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Marks the record with the specified ID as undeleted.
    w.Write([]byte("Marks deleted records as undeleted."))
}

func RecordPurge(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Permanently deletes the record with the specified ID.
    w.Write([]byte("Permanently deletes record with given ID."))
}
```

When I make a request to **localhost:8080/test**, it calls the handler function in the main package and prints "Test output.". But any of the other defined URLs return a `200 OK` status code and an empty (0 bytes) response body instead of the expected text.

I'm fairly sure this is *something* to do with the `ResponseWriter` object being passed through but I can't figure out why it works for one function in the same package but not another function in a different package, even though both functions have a copy of the writer passed through. I've tried a few different ways of writing including `fmt.FPrintf`, `io.WriteString`, and `w.Write`, to no avail.

Comment: This should work. Make sure that the installed version of your `infrastructure/routing` package is up to date.

Comment: It's my own package, and I've posted it in full. I don't understand what the issue could be if it works from a function in the same package but not from one in a different one.

Comment: Yes, I mean make sure the installed object files are up to date with `go install infrastructure/routing` (though if that works, it would be interesting to know why it's *not* rebuilding the source). You can also see exactly what's going on by using the  `-x` flag when you build/install your `main` package.

Comment: Huh. Looks like a clean & build all worked. I'm using LiteIDE and I've just been pressing build individually on all the packages I changed. Going to use build all from now on. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I tested on my machine and everything works. I get 200 responses. But when I send many requests at the same time, some of the responses are 0 instead of 200. You might want to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turns out when I was building my code for whatever reason it wasn't keeping the object files updated. I've been using LiteIDE for a while and this is the first time clicking Build on all relevant packages individually hasn't worked.

I cleaned it and then used Build All, now it works.